# Migrating an existing Blazor Wasm app with authentication into MAUI

Tags: authentication, blazor, maui

I have a simple Blazor app (counter) with individual accounts used for authentication (that is provided by Visual Studio template). I would like to move this Blazor app into MAUI as native app on Windows. Do I need to make any changes to the authentication in Blazor? I don't need any local authentication in WPF or Windows. I just want to have the authentication and functionality of the wasm app available from a Windows app.

Comment: I think you need to create a `AuthenticationStateProvider` in maui. You can refer to this article about [Blazor Hybrid authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=maui#handle-authentication-within-the-blazorwebview-option-2).